# Double Vector issue in c++

Tags: c++, vector

So I was looking to make basically a double array but have it be dynamic via vectors. However I guess I do not fully understand this as I am doing something wrong causing my vector to be subscript out of range. Here below is my code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> m_menuList;
m_menuList[0].push_back(menuType);
m_menuList[0].push_back(location);
```

This might be a stupid mistake or something completely wrong, it does compile correctly, just always crashes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We tend to call "double vectors" **2D Vectors.** A "triple vector" would then be a 3D Vector and so on...the whole lot of them can be called **Multidimensional Vectors.**

Your issue is that the outer vector is empty, so there is no `m_menuList[0]`. You could instead do:

```
m_menuList.push_back(std::vector<std::string>(1, menuType));
```

Which will push a vector consisting solely of `menuType` to the back of `m_menuList`.

You can also start `m_menuList` off with a certain number of empty vectors so that your current code would work (assuming you have some integer n):

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> m_menuList(n);
```

Comment: Ah okay, I thought 2D vectors meant like some type of graphic vectors! (blush)... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to `resize()` your vector after initialization before accessing it using index.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> m_menuList;
m_menuList.resize(1);
```

But when you insert objects you dont need index, you can do as follows:

```
m_menuList.push_back(menuType);
m_menuList.push_back(location);

OR

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> m_menuList;
m_menuList.push_back(menuType);
m_menuList.push_back(location);
```